# Java Ring of Fire drinking game

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create a "Ring of Fire" drinking game, have have some issues.

I have added all the card images in the res/drawable folder in Android Studio:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReNJJ.png)

I am using this code to generate a random number from 1-13 and select a card:

```
final int min = 1;
final int max = 13;
private void randomizeCard() {
    final int random = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    Resources res = getResources();
    String mDrawableName = "c"+random;
    int resID = res.getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
    Drawable drawable = ((Resources) res).getDrawable(resID );
    cardImage.setImageDrawable(drawable );
}
```

The problem is that the same card might show up many times. I only want the same card to show up a maximum of 4 times. How can I do this, so one of the cards does not show up more then 4 times?

Comment: Think about how you would do it by hand and describe the steps you need to take **in words**. Then figure out how to translate those words into code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have been trying to figure this out since early yesterday, but I can't seems to find any good solution :/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is use list and shuffle to limit duplicate card

```
    final int min = 1;
    final int max = 13;
    final int duplicate = 4;
    List<Integer> cards = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            for (int j=0 ;j<duplicate; j++) {
                cards.add(i);
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
    }

    int getCard(){
        if(cards.size()>0){
             int val = cards.get(0);
             cards.remove(0);
             return val;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Where do I put this? I tried adding it to the `private void randomizeCard()` code, which runs every time the user pick a new card, but the same cards does show up more then 4 times. EDIT: Also tried adding it in the `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {` but still the same..

Comment: no, u do it once and use the list from the first to last

Comment: Still not working. I ran a test round and I got the King-card 1 time, and 8-of-hearts 4 times.

Comment: Here you have example of my whole code: https://pastebin.com/uJCFpHXi - Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: you not use the getCard function in randomizeCard  https://pastebin.com/5zKG8P7s